# Merge columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns that I know are identical if they have a value greater than 0. I want to know how would I get the non-zero value of each column and merge it into one column

Here is the sample column:

[image]

What I expect is to merge the 3 columns in to one column and get the non-zero value

Output:

[image]

If the value is non-zero, all values on each columns are the same. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `df.bfill(axis=1)` after replacing 0 with `np.nan`

Comment: Is possible negative numbers? If all 3 values are 0 in row, whats happen?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Also, I have a check to not include all rows with zero values. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `max`:

```
df['C'] = df[['C1','C2','C3']].max(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['C'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[0,15,25],
                   'C2':[1,0,25],
                   'C3':[1,15,25]})

x = np.trim_zeros(np.unique(df.values))
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'C':x})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 1],[15, 0, 15],[25, 25, 25]])
df.replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)
```

or using

```
df.max(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [312]: df.replace(0,np.nan).max(1)
Out[312]: 
0     1.0
1    15.0
2    25.0
```